# Share feedback review option - adding link to homework FAQ

Tags: discussion, status-declined, close-reasons, review

In the new "First questions" review queue there is an option to "Share feedback". The current choices are the "unclear" and "too broad" close reasons, but you can share these here without initiating the vote to close.

Is it possible the add the "problematic homework" explanation with a link to the FAQ?

---

Edit: This question incorrectly stated that the "opinion-based" share feedback option was already implemented, but it isn't. Is it possible to add that as well?

Comment: I tried to research way to edit it and unless I missed something we mods cannot edit those messages so I added status-review tag to your Q, some CM's can either help or explain why it can't be at the moment implemented

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not possible customize changes here on an individual site. Currently changes in the review queue are network wide which is why I updated the tag to `status-declined`. Customizing close reasons isn't on the current roadmap. If it's something that is prioritized in the future we can revisit this request.